# SQL Server Text Searching

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, text-search

I have a business requirement where we need to do somce crazy name matching against records stored in the database and I was wondering if there is any easy way to do it using SQL Server.

Name Stored in the DB : Austin K
Name to be Matched from UI : Austin Kierland

That's just a sample. In reality, there could be whole lot of different permutations and combinations.

If it's other way round, I could've used wild character but in this case, the name in the database is smaller than the search criteria.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Be somewhat careful of [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0):

Realistically - no. Databases were meant for comparing absolute values, not for messy comparisons. The way they store their data internally just isn't fit for really messy matching. Actually even a superpowerful dedicated search engine like Google, that has a *LOT* of messy matching features, wouldn't be able to pull off your example without prior knowledge.

I don't know how the requirement is precisely worded, but I'd either shoot the feature request with "technically impossible", or implement a rule set for which messy matches are tried - for your example, you could easily 'hard code' that multiple searches are executed when capitalized words are entered, shortening them so a single letter. No idea if that's a solution to your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a normal search using the LIKE operator which determines whether a specific character string matches a specified pattern.  The problem you will run into is the probability of the returning of multiple records or incorrect people.  I've had similar requirement myself for a business app and the best solution to the issue is to require other qualifying values rather then just name.  If you do a partial name search without other qualifying data you are certainly going to come across the false positive matches and/or multiple records.  In my case  I built a web service that checks eligibility allowing text search for first & last name but also added date of birth, primary person SSN, and gender which ensured the matching person was in deed the person intended to search for.   If my situation was like yours in which name was the only search criteria my recommendation to the business would be we cannot perform the search until qualifying data is entered into the database otherwise there is no accurate way to query the results they are looking for.